# Prism navigation - how to handle child view initialisation and cleanup?

Tags: prism, prism-4

I have a "parent" view containing several regions, into which I load other views. These "child" views are always the same and don't change at runtime, so they are registered with their regions during application startup, using the `regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion...` syntax. All the views are currently singletons, and I use Castle Windsor for IoC.

Bearing in mind that 'INavigationAware' methods don't get called on view-models in nested regions, what's a good approach for initialisation and cleanup of my child views? Is it an "acceptable" design for the parent VM to hold references (injected) to the child VM? I could then call some kind of init/cleanup methods on the child VMs from within the parent's `OnNavigatedTo()/From()` method?

Another option might be to change the views to transient, then I could simply use the constructor for initialisation, and not worry about cleanup (which I only do to clear down old "state" before the view is re-used and displayed).
The only potential issue is that my application uses an "event service" (similar to Prism's event broker), with some view-models acting as publishers and others as subscribers. I'm concerned that if I made them transient, the view-models won't get GC'd because of the event subscription, and these "dead" views would continue responding to events. Is this correct? If so, do I presumably need to implement a way of cleaning up (as above), where I can unsubscribe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've came across the same problem, a while back.

The way I did it was to implement the INavigationAware interface on the Parent ViewModel and in the ViewModels of those scoped Regions/Views and then on the Parent ViewModel  OnNavigatedFrom method, call the OnNavigatedFrom of the children ViewModels.

Bear in mind that you have to keep a reference of the Children ViewModels in the Parent ViewModel (which I believe is not a bad practice). This reference can be injected by the Container and deleted (Teared Down) when you navigate away from the Parent View (depending  on the value of the KeepAlive property if you've implemented  the IRegionMemberLifetime in the parent and children  ViewModels).

Comment: Thanks, I had thought of this too but it seems a bit clunky and wondered if there was something built into Prism. Guess not - this issue seems to appear over and over again on forums and it's a shame the Prism developers haven't made this sort of thing a little easier to manage. I guess this approach won't work though if the views/VMs are transient, as you won't get the same instance being injected!

Comment: It depends. If your parent ViewModel/View is responsible for getting the instance of the childs and set each as a property, this can be binded as the datacontext of the childviews. Using this approach you can use the KeepAlive to manage the lifetime of the View and it's respective ViewModels, e.g. , the ViewModels will only be fetched from the Container (by the Parent ViewModel) when a new instance of the Parent View is fetched from the Container.

In either case, I believe that if the Views are transient, then the ViewModels should be as well.

Comment: As long as you don't share the same instance of a ViewModel across different instances of the same View , it's fine.